# How can I apply regularization to Stable Diffusion V2.0?

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface, huggingface-datasets, stable-diffusion, image-generation

I am in the process of fine tuning the text to image model and Dreambooth model of Stable Diffusion v2.0. However, I want to apply regularization in case the model forgets certain concepts (class: dog, etc.) during learning, but I cannot find regulation or class-related parameters in stable diffusion's train python code.

How can I do this? Should I mix it with the train data? What ratio(train: regularization) is good?

And how should we structure the data set? I'm planning to proceed locally.(or even huggingface-hub)

Thank you for your answer.

I followed https://github.com/bmaltais/kohya_ss/tree/master and applied it to the stable diffusion 1.0 base model, which was successful. But it wasn't possible for v2.0.